# How to process two variable values in ascending order using Python

Tags: python

I have two variable names with each containing an `int` value. I am trying to figure out how to process the first variable name with the highest number e.g.: `v1 = 10`and `v2 =11`, do function a because `v2` is highest
so far I have this code

```
timesort = sorted(iter(NrOfRows0, NrOfRows1))
print 'order%' + iter(timesort)
```

it gives me errors.

Comment: By any chance does the unspecified error say something like `TypeError: iter(NrOfRows0, NrOfRows1): NrOfRows0 must be callable`? If not, what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what you wanted to do if they both had the same high value, but I think this will get you going in the right direction

```
nr0 = sorted(NrOfRows0)
nr1 = sorted(NrOfRows1)
if nr0[-1] > nr1[-1]:
    print 'use nr0'
else:
    print 'use nr1'
```

Comment: how about if I have ten list of variable name and I want to print them in ascending order? I know I can use some sort of for loop to do that?

Comment: You'll need to pass the list of NrOfRows (ie: a list of lists), then iterate lists, sorting each in turn, and testing each for the 'best' nr[-1] value.  It shouldn't take more than a few minutes of experimentation to get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use larger of two ints, you can just use [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)

```
v1 = 10
v2 = 11

print max(v1, v2) # Prints 11
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Hamati. I think I need to re-phrase my question because I AM LOOKING TO PRINT THE SECOND value, third value etc..in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this? Maybe you can use [locals()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals).

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    v1 = 10
    v2 = 11
    localDict = {k:v for k, v in locals().items() if not k.startswith("__")}
    localDict = dict(sorted(localDict.items(), key = lambda x : -x[1]))
    for k , v in localDict:
        print("%s = %s" % (k, v))
```

Comment: I want to process the highest value not to print both. Well it's a good idea but then I want to print them in ascending order and I don't really understand your code. I am new in python, I will have to test it. but then is your code print when both value are the same?